# In Obj-c/iOS would it be best to store seconds as an int or a NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In Obj-c/iOS would it be best to store seconds as an int or a NSNumber? unfortunately I'm not able to use NSTime, as I'm storing it on a server, and they don't do NSTime.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What? How the server is relevant? What does 'storing' mean?

Comment: I'm using Parse, you can't store NSTime on there, they suggested I store the time in seconds, and us NSNumber, but then I don't see why I can't use an INT instead, but since I'm new to obj-c I don't know if there's a reason to choose one over other hence the question.

Comment: Must it be an integral type? `NSTimeInterval` is the normal primitive type for 'amounts of time in seconds' but it's a `double`.

Comment: Parse told me use a NSNumber. Is NSNumber better somehow when it comes to converting seconds to NSTimeInterval or NSTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it really matters so for simplicity I'd say an int just because it doesn't need to be initialized.